# Creating View from table with duplicated rows

Tags: postgresql, view, amazon-redshift

I have a table that has semi-duplicated rows (due to an error with pixels sending information through alooma multiple times). My goal is to dedupe this table and then create a view based off of that deduping.

Example of table structure;

```
    Col1   Col2   Col3    Col4
    x      y      z       w
    x      y      z       p
    x      y      z       z
```

All of the rows are equal other than col4. I don't have the ability to fix the duplication/alooma issue, so we need a view that would only return 1 row for every duplication.

Comment: How would you decide which one to return?

Answer (score 0):

If col4 is meaningless, you can use DISTINCT and only select the relevant columns like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 FROM your_table
```

For your example data this would return one row of x, y, z.

If you don't care about col4 values, but for some reason want the column included, here's a pretty simple way to get only distinct rows according to the other, relevant columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2, col3) * FROM your_table
```

For your example data this would return one row of x, y, z, p. The "p" value being chosen "randomly".